# помогите с python

Tags: python

помогите, пожалуйста, что за ошибка? Не могу понять.

```
fruit == 'apple'
if fruit is 'apple'
print("fruit is apple")
else:
   print("lala")
```

Answer (score 3):

- Имя `fruit` не определено, Вы используете оператор сравнения (`==`), вместо оператора присваивания (`=`).
- Пропущено двоеточие после условия
- Нет отступа перед телом цикла
- Вы используете оператор `is`, вместо оператора сравнения (`==`)

***Пример:***

```py
fruit = 'apple'

if fruit == 'apple':
    print('fruit is apple')
else:
    print('lala')
```

***stdout:***

```html
fruit is apple
```

Answer (score 2):

Двоеточия нет и отступ неверный.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103300/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy---python).

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica А зачем вандализировать сообшение?

Comment: Прошу конечно  прощения за навязчивый вопрос, но по логу изменений не совсем понял что это -- война правок или игра в правки?

Comment: @0xdb, чатик выше.

Answer (score 2):

После `if` должно быть `:` и таб, то есть:

```
if fruit == 'apple':
     print("fruit is apple")
```

Но не понятно, что значит `fruit == 'apple' # сравнение`, что просто вернет `false`
Наверное, должно было быть: `fruit = apple # присваивание`
И ещё тут не подходит оператор `is`, [почитайте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator) зачем он нужен

Comment: SyntaxWarning на это будет.